# MacOS - requesting audio/camera permission - wrong app title shown?

Tags: macos, permissions

We are asking for permission to use audio and camera in our Mac app. In general this works OK.

But there is one quirk. If we launch our app from another app, such as from Terminal -

When the permission prompt comes up, the app that is identifed as requesting access is the top level application ie. Terminal, not our app name.

[image: Wrong app title on permission]

If our app is run independently from finder (etc), the correct title shows up in the permission prompt.

[image]

I thought it might be a missing CFBundleDisplayName, but that doesn't help.

```
void PERMISSIONS::checkAudioPermission() const
{
   if (@available(macOS 10.14, *))
   {
      AVAuthorizationStatus audioAuthStatus =
         [AVCaptureDevice authorizationStatusForMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
      if (audioAuthStatus != AVAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
      {
         // If the user has not definitively said Yes or No, ask them to do so.
         if (audioAuthStatus == AVAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
         {
            [AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio
               completionHandler:^(BOOL granted)
            {
               if (granted)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is actually a vulnerability that Apple has never fixed, which could be exploited by malware. This is discussed by Patrick Wardle at his site:

https://objective-see.com/blog/blog_0x2F.html

Therefore, I highly encourage you to file a bug, so that this can be fixed.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks. That blog post seems to confirm that it's the top level app, whatever that is, that is checked for permissions, not the code actually running. it's not just cosmetic, it's actually a flawed security model?

Comment: Absolutely. Patrick has filed for this bug several times, but Apple keeps ignoring this piggy-backing flaw. Thus, the more complaints they get the likeliest they will pay attention to it.

Comment: Sure, I will. Do you/he suggest filing it as some kind of API bug or as a security problem? Actually I'm not sure that I would know how to write a security problem report.

Comment: I suggest that Apple may have done it this way for backwards compatibility, espeically things like Apple script, which don't have bundle IDs of their own

Comment: No, just file the bug as you described here: that the expected outcome was that the name of the real app to be shown to the user and not the app that launched the app which wants access to the microphone or the camera. About applescripts not having a bundle ID cannot be an excuse. We users can transform scripts into apps with entitlements and all with just the Script Editor.

Comment: OK thanks for clarifying. Now fighting the feedback assistant :/

Comment: Submitted feedback FB6734212.

Comment: Well, I got feedback: Apple Aug 6, 2019 at 12:02 PM
This is working as designed. The open command in terminal to open app would attribute access to the app.

Comment: Amazing, that is really a weak answer from them. It is true that the access is being granted to the app requesting it, but the point is that the WRONG app name is being shown to the user.

Comment: I'm not sure that is true. If you look in the system preferences, the wrong name shows there as well. I think the access is genuinely being granted to the wrong thing.

Comment: Anyway, I'm thinking to reply "it may be as designed, but the behaviour is deceptive and unhelpful to the user and developer"

Comment: I agree. Please do that. Thanks.

Comment: I said this: It may be "as designed" but the designed behaviour is deceptive/confusing/unhelpful. The app which is actually requesting the access should be the one that is attributed the access, regardless of how the app was opened.

Comment: Well ... Now Apple says: When is an app is launched via the GUI or the "open" command, the systems knows an app is running on behalf of a (real) user and can attribute access requests to that app. When a app is started is other ways (e.g. from the command line), the system cannot attribute access to the app.

Comment: That seems like they are just saying an excuse to me.

Comment: Something very similar sounding with inherited permissions seems to have been exploited https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2021/05/hackers-exploit-a-macos-0day-that-allows-them-to-screenshot-infected-macs/

Comment: Indeed, finally they fixed it since it was found to be exploited in the wild.

Comment: Are you sure it’s the same thing? Frustrating

Comment: Not sure, but looks similar. You can always try now if your issue was solved upon upgrading to this OS version.

Comment: Yeah. Ironically, my laptop won't support Big Sur so I can't test this yet